# how to open select list by clicking a button in jQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox, jquery-triggerhandler

```
<body>
    <form>
        <select name="test" id="test">
            <option value="one">one</option>
            <option value="two">two</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <button>Open Select Bar</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my html codes and I want to open the select list by clicking on the button in jquery, and I am unable to understand that how can I achieve it .
Someone suggest me the way to achieve it,

Comment: What you mean by open select list ?

Comment: Please Don't Write With Upper Case Letters Like This. It Is Very Annoying To Read Text Like That.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all give some `id` or `class` to your button. (For example I give id on snippet.)
2. Use select box attribute `size`  to open your select list using `option` and `length` when button click.

```js
$('#btnselect').click(function(e) {
  $('#test').attr('size', $('option').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" id="test">
  <option value="one">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
</select>

<button id='btnselect'>Open Select Bar</button>
```

Comment: Still it is not opening

Comment: Run snippet  it's work